# Why doesn't replacing double quotes in arguments work?

Tags: string, variables, cmd, arguments, setvalue

I want to have a batch script argument as a string which possibly contains spaces. I need to put it inside double quotes:

```
script.bat "hello world"
```

Now, in the script I need modify it. So I need to remove the quotes. In my test, using `%a:"=%` should work:

```
set a="hello world" & echo %a%
"hello world"
set b=%a:"=% & echo %b%
hello world
```

However this doesn't work if the variable is an input argument:

```
echo %1%
"hello world"
set b=%1:"=% & echo %b%
"hello world":"=
```

I manage to solve this by using a temp variable:

```
echo %1%
"hello world"
set a=%1% & echo %a%
"hello world"
set b=%a:"=% & echo %b%
hello world
```

But I still wonder why you can't directly work with `%1%`?

Comment: Arguments are represented by `%1`, not `%1%`. Substring processing is not possible with them. Assign the parameter to a "normal" variable `set "var1=%~1"` to further do substring processing. The tilde removes surrounding quotes, so just `echo %~1` should do in your usecase.

Comment: Put the `echo` commands in the next lines rather than appending them with `&` to get the actual variable value…

Comment: @Stephan why does the tilde remove the surrounding quotes?

Comment: because it's built to do so. See `call /?` for more details.